# Sapply function for element-wise calculation a matrix in R

Tags: r, loops, matrix, apply, sapply

I have an (5x4) matrix in `R`, namely `data` defined as follows:

```
set.seed(123)    
data <- matrix(rnorm(5*4,mean=0,sd=1), 5, 4)
```

and I want to create 4 different matrices that follows this formula: Assume that `data[,1] = [A1,A2,A3,A4,A5]`. I want to create the following matrix:

```
        A1-A1 A1-A2 A1-A3 A1-A4 A1-A5 
        A2-A1 A2-A2 A2-A3 A2-A4 A2-A5
   G1 = A3-A1 A3-A2 A3-A3 A3-A4 A3-A5
        A4-A1 A4-A2 A4-A3 A4-A4 A4-A5
        A5-A1 A5-A2 A5-A3 A5-A4 A5-A5
```

Similarly for the other columns i want to calculate at once all the G matrices (`G1`,`G2`,`G3`,`G4`). How can i achieve that with the `sapply` funciton?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We may use elementwise subtraction of column with `outer`

```
outer(data[,1], data[,1], `-`)
```

If it should be done on each column, loop over the columns (or do `asplit` with `MARGIN = 2` to split by column), loop over the `list` and apply the `outer`

```
lapply(asplit(data, 2), function(x) outer(x, x, `-`))
```

Comment: Thank you. The outer function seems to works perfectly.